# Recompiling Lightspeed-C program from the 80's

Tags: c

Im trying to recompile an old program called QLSconvert for the Kurzweil K250 synthesizer.
The source code: https://www25.zippyshare.com/v/NLzuTUn6/file.html 
The application runs in Lightspeed-C 3.0.1 at least in the emulator that im using, Vmac mini, with a mac ii ROM and system 6.
The error im getting when trying to recompile is:
"macro name is already #define'd"
I'm not too familiar with C to be honest, so any tips on how to resolve this error would be super useful.
I can only share an image of the error and not type it out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p2WH.jpg
Another question I have is, I need to be able to compile this program in 32-bit, as it is currently a 24-bit addressing application.
I'm not sure if it can be done with Lightspeed-C 3.0.1 or if I would need Think C 5.0.1, which is the first version to apparently be able to create 32-bit apps.

Comment: It would really help if they told you *which* macro was already defined.  If you can edit the source, you could try adding `#undef  MAX` and `#undef MIN` before those first two defines.  If you still get the error, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Alright, that did something....now im getting a different error from a different file: https://imgur.com/a/IvLjrdZ

Comment: That's not how this site works. You can't post links to off-site code, an image of an error, and expect us to solve the problem for you. You also can't post additional questions in the same post, whether it's in comments or the post itself. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, particularly [ask] and [mcve], to learn how to use this site properly.

Comment: C is a very simple language to learn. You can learn it in a few days of reading, if you know how to program. After a few days of work, you'll be able to understand the C code that you want to compile and to figure out what your error message means. In your case, it is a *very* simple thing; related to the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Start by reading that wikipage.

Comment: The most difficult things in C are pointers and [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) and your error message is not related to them. It is a very simple error.

Comment: If you are not capable of understanding the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) wikipage, pay someone who can and who will help you. It is probably a one hour job to compile your old code for any person knowing C. You'll find many of them near you. Propose them 100$ or 100€ for that one hour job. Put an ad in your vicinity offering that.